# does a univariate polynomial have a unique factorization?

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

Specifically, if $\mathbb{G}$ is a not necessarily Archimedean ordered group, does the class $\mathbb{Z}(T^\mathbb{G})$ of polynomials in one variable $T$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ and exponents in $\mathbb{G}$ have unique factorization?

EDIT: I've been informed that $\mathbb{Z}(T^\mathbb{G})$ is the integral group algebra of $\mathbb{G}$, and that this is perhaps a more concise way to express my question. Does it help if $\mathbb{G}$ is discretely ordered?

EDIT: Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a unique factorization domain, I would expect any polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ to also be a unique factorization domain -- it's really the non-Archimedean property for the exponent class that makes me curious as to whether this still holds.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what is meant: This is the group algebra, right?

Comment: I'm wondering if the elements of $\mathbb{Z}(T^\mathbb{G})$ admit unique prime factorizations, where polynomial multiplication behaves in the expected sense -- I believe it is valid to view $\mathbb{Z}(T^\mathbb{G})$ as the group algebra of $\mathbb{G}$ 'weighted' in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If polynomials are multiplied the expected way then this is indeed the integral group algebra. It is probably a bad idea to call it polynomial as it usually behaves much differently than a polynomial algebra, though I have not thought that much about how the group being ordered helps with this.

Comment: Generally speaking, any non-Archimedean ordered group can be identified with a subgroup of an initial subfield of the Surreal numbers, and has all the structure that comes along with such an identification.

I'm not very familiar with the notion of a group algebra, but thank you for the clarification -- I considered 'Hahn series' or some such instead of 'polynomials', but I only want a finite number of terms in the 'polynomial'.

Answer (score 3):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}(T^{\mathbb{G}})$ is not necessarily a unique factorization domain, even if $\mathbb{G}$ is Archimedean.

For example, take $\mathbb{G} = \mathbb{Q}$.  Then for any integer $s$, we have that
$$
(1-T^{2^s}) = (1-T^{2^{s-1}})(1+T^{2^{s-1}}).
$$
This implies that we have an ascending chain of ideals
$$
(1-T) \subset (1-T^{\frac{1}{2}}) \subset (1-T^{\frac{1}{4}}) \subset \ldots \subset (1-T^{\frac{1}{2^s}}) \subset\ldots
$$
in $\mathbb{Z}(T^{\mathbb{Q}})$.  The inclusions in the chain are strict.  Therefore, the ring does not satisfy the ascending chain condition on principal ideals.  Since [unique factorization domains have to satisfy this condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Properties), the ring $\mathbb{Z}(T^{\mathbb{Q}})$ is not a unique factorization domain.

Comment: What if $\mathbb{G}$ is discretely ordered?

Comment: It seems to me that this argument depends explicitly on the fact that you picked a densely ordered group -- if the value group behaves more like a polynomial value group in the sense that it is discretely ordered, for example the Grothendieck group of any $\delta$-number ordinal $\delta>\omega$ under natural operations, does unique factorization still fail?

Comment: I feel like unique factorization should probably be true if the group is discretely ordered.  The proof would probably follow the same lines as the proof that $\mathbb{Z}[T]$ is a UFD: define a degree, prove Gauss' Lemma and prove the result for $\mathbb{Q}[T]$.

Comment: That seems like a promising route of attack -- much appreciated.

Comment: @AlecRhea Just out of curiosity, what is an example of a discretely ordered group which is not just the integers?

Comment: I construct a proper class of non-isomorphic discretely ordered groups in this paper ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08908 ) using ordered pairs of ordinals and Hessenberg addition/multiplication -- that part of the construction begins on page 26. I'm not aware of these appearing anywhere else -- I also construct densely ordered fields of fractions for each, and then cut up the fraction fields to obtain real-closed fields.

Comment: I believe you could also consider the Grothendieck group of any δ-number greater than $\omega$, such as $\omega^{\omega}$, under Hessenberg addition and multiplication -- this group is the smallest discretely ordered group containing a subgroup that is isomorphic to the integers, and you can keep going to $\omega^{\omega^2}$, $\omega^{\omega^3}$, etc. These are equivalent to the class of all Cantor normal forms with positive and negative integer coefficients, and I prove that the integers are the only cyclic discretely ordered group up to isomorphism.

Comment: Actually, you could close out an additive group at any $\gamma$-number like $\omega^2$, $\omega^3$, $\dots$. In order to close out a ring, we need to go to a $\delta$-number like $\omega^\omega$.